# increasing and decreasing font size in custom font j2me

Tags: java-me, fonts

My j2me application uses a custom font in res folder 
res
font-18
font-24
font-27
which are fonts with separate sizes for matching screen resolutions. 
and i use

```
if(resolution<=small)
{
font-res ="font-18.res";
}
else if(resolution<=large)
{
font-res ="font-27.res";
}
```

and so on..But now that my jar size exceeds 2mb i have to think of decreasing the items in res and found removing any 2 makes a big difference in jar size. (It becomes <2mb) .Is there any other means of doing this? Please help me to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are creating your custom fonts or how they are stored or how many different sizes you're talking about, but I can tell you that I am currently developing an app where I have included 13 different sizes of a custom font, and those 13 files only use 175kb of space in total.

Those 13 font sizes are currently stored as unoptimized 24bit PNG files. When/if I optimize them, using a tool like pngout or optipng, then they'll take up even less space.

There are a number of things you can do to reduce jar size in general, such as obfuscating the code (a functionality that's usually built into your IDE nowadays, and is just a matter of you turning it on in your project properties).

Some people claim that earlier versions of JDK creates a 5-20% smaller JAR size than later JDK versions. I haven't tried this myself.

But you can find lots of additional info if you google for it.